# unable to parse puppet template nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, puppet

```
Filepath:/etc/puppet/environments/learning_bb_check/modules/sdsds/templates/learning-config.erb
Line: 3
Detail: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: erb template  [user]
        uri = host
        username = <%= @_user_name['user'] %>
        password = <%= @_user_pass['pass'] %>

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: // , Is this a question, or are you just copying and pasting error output?

Answer (score 0):

Your template assumes that in Puppet's scope, there are variables `$_user_name` and `$_user_pass`, both of type hash.

Apparently there are not.

Did you write this "learning" module yourself? What was your approach to designing the ERB template?